# Check if Filename is of Form <filename>.<md5sum of file content>

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting

In Bash, how can I most easily check that the filename of a regular file is of the format shown below?

> ```
> <filename>.<md5sum of file content>
> ```

For example, assume I had a file whose original name was **foo.txt** and had this content:

> Hello world

The md5sum of this file is:

> f0ef7081e1539ac00ef5b761b4fb01b3

Therefore, I have already changed the filename to:

> foo.txt.f0ef7081e1539ac00ef5b761b4fb01b3

How, in Bash, may I best do the string processing necessary to verify that the portion of the filename after the last dot is indeed the md5sum of the file's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering a bash script where you give the filename you want to test as parameter :

```
./script.sh filename.f0ef7081e1539ac00ef5b761b4fb01b3
```

content of `script.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get the md5 value from the filename (get the substring after the last '.' character)
expectedMD5=${1##*.}

#Calculate the md5sum value of the file
realMD5=$( md5sum $1 | awk '{ print $1 }' )

#Compare the 2 values
if [ $expectedMD5 = $realMD5 ]
then
        echo 'OK !'
else
        echo 'NOT OK'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Félicien wrote is the gist of the answer. I just wanted to add that `md5sum` has a *verification* mode:

> ```
> md5sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> -c, --check
>        read MD5 sums from the FILEs and check them
> ```

You could use it as follows. Assuming that `f` contains the file name, then

```
md5sum -c <( echo "${f##*.}" $f )
```

prints out

```
foo.txt.f0ef7081e1539ac00ef5b761b4fb01b3: OK
```

This uses a Bash trick known as [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). Essentially, the command first executes

```
echo "${f##*.}" $f
```

which prints out

```
f0ef7081e1539ac00ef5b761b4fb01b3 foo.txt.f0ef7081e1539ac00ef5b761b4fb01b3
```

But since `md5sum -c` takes it input from a file, rather than from standard input, the output of the `echo` needs to be directed into a temporary location in order for `md5sum` to ingest it, which is done with the `<()` construct.